# TransactionScope doesn't rollback a query

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, transactionscope

I've 2 queries that must work together. First is an *Update* and second is an *Insert* query. I placed them into *TransactionScope* scope:

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    SqlCommand updateCmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE V_Stock SET Quantity= 5 WHERE Id=" + shelfId, con);
    SqlCommand insertCmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO V_Stock (Code, Quantity,   Name) VALUES (@1, @2, @3)", con);
    insertCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", "Code1");
    insertCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", 15);
    insertCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@3", "Name1");
    try
    {
        updateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        insertCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();            
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        scope.Complete();
        string s = ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

The update query works properly however the insert query doesn't. In this case, I don't want to execute them. They should be executed when only they work properly.

What can I do to work these queries together?

Comment: drop `scope.Dispose()` line, using() will do this for you. also why you need s variable in catch? perhaps missing logging?

Comment: Calling `scope.Dispose()` is unnecessary, the `using` already does that. You do need to call `scope.Complete()` explicitly after your queries are done, though, otherwise the scope *will* rollback. Moreover, it's not clear what you mean with "doesn't rollback" and "work together". What are you trying to achieve and what's actually happening?

Comment: Also, after you calls to `ExecuteNonQuery`, you need to call `scope.Complete()` to commit the transaction.

Comment: It doesn't work also that I use scope.Complete() after ExecuteNonQuery()

Answer (score 4):

- You need to call `scope.Complete` when you are ready to commit your transaction, not when it fails.
- You should also open the connections inside the scope of the `TransactionScope` so the connection is registered with that scope.
- Also I am not sure where your `SqlConnection` instance is defined. The Microsoft team always recommends you use short lived connections, use them and get rid of them. Let Sql Server handle connection pooling (usually this is on by default) which makes it very cheap to use and throw away sql connections inside your c# code.

Here is some refactored code and I added some documentation that I found on the Microsoft definition for [TransactionScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(yourConnectString))
    {
        // according to the documentation on TransactionScope
        // Opening the connection automatically enlists it in the 
        // TransactionScope as a lightweight transaction.
        con.Open();

        // I changed this to make it parameterized as well although this had nothing to do with the TransactionScope question
        SqlCommand updateCmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE V_Stock SET Quantity= 5 WHERE Id= @shelfId", con);
        updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@shelfId", shelfId);

        SqlCommand insertCmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO V_Stock (Code, Quantity, Name) VALUES (@1, @2, @3)", con);
        insertCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", "Code1");
        insertCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", 15);
        insertCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@3", "Name1");

        updateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        insertCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();            

        // according to the documentation on TransactionScope
        // The Complete method commits the transaction. If an exception has been thrown,
        // Complete is not  called and the transaction is rolled back.
        scope.Complete();
    }
}
```